# Redirect on Empty Query Var

Tags: plugin-development, rewrite-rules, template-redirect, redirect

I have a plugin with two rewrite rules:

```
public static function cp_libdatabases_add_rewrites(){
     $options = get_option( 'libdatabases_plugin_options' );
     $staff_url = $options['staff_url'];

     //accept characters A-Z (last name letter)
     add_rewrite_rule('^'.$staff_url.'/libdb/([A-Z]+)/?', 'index.php?libdb=$matches[1]', 'top');
     add_rewrite_rule('^'.$staff_url.'/libsubj/([A-Z]+)/?', 'index.php?libsubj=$matches[1]', 'top');
  }
```

Depending on the query var, the user is redirected to the appropriate template:

```
public static function cp_libdatabases_template_redirect(){
  global $wp_query;

  if ( get_query_var( 'libdb' ) ){
    add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
        return LIBDATABASES__PLUGIN_DIR . '/controllers/c.database.php';
    });
  }

  if ( get_query_var( 'libsubj' ) ){
    add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
        return LIBDATABASES__PLUGIN_DIR . '/controllers/c.subject.php';
    });
  }
}
```

This works when the query var 'libdb' or 'libsubj' has an argument associated with it:

http://example.com/databases/libdb/A/

But I want to be able to show ALL results if the URL is typed in as:

http://example.com/databases/libdb/

I'm unclear on how to tweak my re-direct to achieve this; If I input the URL without the final argument I am sent to the 404 page.

**SOLUTION**

The regex was missing a leading question mark. Also, replace the + with *:

**?**([A-Z1-9]*)/?

You must also amend the template_redirect() function to check if the 'libdb' query_var is set:

```
public static function cp_libdatabases_template_redirect(){
  global $wp_query;
  $query_vars = $wp_query->query_vars;

  if ( isset($query_vars['libdb']) ){
    add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
        return LIBDATABASES__PLUGIN_DIR . '/controllers/c.database.php';
    });
  }

  if ( isset($query_vars['libsubj']) ){
    add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
        return LIBDATABASES__PLUGIN_DIR . '/controllers/c.subject.php';
    });
  }
```

}

Skipping either of these steps result in the 404. Including these steps allows you to show a list of all records if an argument is not supplied.

Comment: If your question is not a duplicate of the one I marked as such, please explain exactly why not.

Comment: No I don't think this is necessarily a duplicate for two reasons.

1) When you dump the query vars with an extra argument supplied to (/libdb/A), the result is different than when you have just (/libdb) in the URL
- ["libdb"]=> string(1) "A"  (when /libdb/A)
- ["attachment"]=> string(5) "libdb" (when /libdb)

2. None of the examples on those posts work.

Comment: And what are those two reasons?

Comment: Basically Wordpress is not reading libdb as a query var at all when there is no extra argument supplied to /libdb. Hence there is always a 404 error.

Comment: Which sounds like exactly the problem addressed in what I believe to be a duplicate. Did you try any of those solutions?

Comment: Yes. Nothing has worked thus far. Either way I'm going through some similar questions and trying to find something that works. It's quite possible I'm just not doing it right. I'll post something if I find something that works.

Comment: And what do you know...got it. Thanks for the lead.